# Containers issue with Jenkins plugin for Kubernetes

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, devops

I'm using kubernetes plugin in jenkins. I'm trying to use it with Pipeline and Freestyle jobs.
The jobs are running, but only in container with name `jnlp-slave:3.35-5-alpine` which I did't define anywhere.

Even if define the image in the pipeline nothing happanig and still running in this `jnlp-slave:3.35-5-alpine` image. Here is example of my pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage ('Stage as dsl') {
            agent {
                kubernetes {
                    cloud 'kubernetes'
                    label 'jnlp-slave'
                    containerTemplate {
                        name 'jnlp-slave'
                        image 'jnlp-slave'
                    }
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh '''
                    pwd; \
                    whoami; \
                    uname -a
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Where is my mistake?**

Comment: Maybe label is the thing you need to change? As mentioned in jenkins doc `label ->The label of the pod. Can be set to a unique value to avoid conflicts across builds`. So if I understand it correctly, now it's should work only on pod with label k8s-jnlp-slave and the latest image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I find is to **NOT** define any label for the cluster.

In my `jenkinsfile` example I'm testing to use diffrend docker images like this:

**Working Solution**

```
def podTemplate = """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: java-slave
    image: myrepo/java-slave:latest
    command:
    - sleep
    args:
    - infinity
  - name: jenkins-slave-dind
    image: myrepo/jenkins-slave-dind:latest
    command:
    - sleep
    args:
    - infinity
    volumeMounts:
    - name: dockersock
      mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
  volumes:
  - name: dockersock
    hostPath:
      path: /var/run/docker.sock
"""
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            yaml podTemplate
            defaultContainer 'java-slave'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Main') {
            steps {
                sh 'curl google.com'
            }
        }
        stage ('Stage as dsl 4'){
            steps {
                container('jenkins-slave-dind') {
                    sh '''
                        docker ps -a
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```